# Create multiple copies of report in pdf format for the same .jrxml

Tags: java, pdf, jasper-reports

I'm working with *iReport 5.1.0*, in a typical case i need to generate a pdf where the contents are duplicated three times in a single pdf, I have created .jrxml file generated 
the pdf. Now i need this pdf to be generated 2 more times with only changing parameter as 
Copy 1, Copy 2, Copy 3.

I have tried to solve this issue with the help of foll. post but it didn't yield the result what i wanted.

[iReport multiple copies of same report with different label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10912710/ireport-multiple-copies-of-same-report-with-different-label)

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: do you want to say that you want to generate 3 pdf file with different data. Is this right?

Comment: Actually i m not doing any java programming part in this report, i've created a .jrxml file with a query(SELECT item_master.`id` AS item_master_id FROM `item_master` item_master) which will get me the details & have added some images, static text etc. When i see it in preview its fine but i need 2 more copy of this in a same pdf, with heading  in each page as Copy1, Copy2, Copy3.

Comment: @ user1791574 No i dont want to generate 3 pdf file with different data, i need to generate pdf with same data 3 times, only change i those pages will be like Copy - 1/2/3

Comment: @Amit Are you going to write *Java* code or not? I don't understand you

Comment: You can use 3 subreport in one main report.you will fill your data in subreport. may be it will help you.

Comment: @Alex i am not writing any java program to generate the PDF...i am trying generate the report with data supplied by the query in ireport designer...

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out if you don't intend to run java code then you can manually write in Copy1/2/3 in the report before generating it.

If you are going to write a java code, then.

Take a loop.

```
For(int i=0;i<3;i++)
```

**Declare heading as the text field. Pass the heading(copy1/2/3) from the code as a report parameter. Map this report parameter to the text field.**